# TypeError: firestoreService.snapshot_ is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've been using firebase functions test to do some testing on my functions. I have some code that is supposed to post a thing to firestore, basically in the same way that the examples show to do in the realtime database examples:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const original = req.query.text;

  admin.firestore()
    .collection('messages')
    .add({ original })
    .then(documentReference => res.send(documentReference))
    .catch(error => res.send(error));
});
```

For my test, I've spoofed some basic functionality using sinon, mocha and chai. Here is my current test, which is failing with the error message: `TypeError: firestoreService.snapshot_ is not a function`

```
 describe('addMessage', () => {
    // add message should add a message to the database
    let oldDatabase;
    before(() => {
        // Save the old database method so it can be restored after the test.
        oldDatabase = admin.firestore;
    });

    after(() => {
        // Restoring admin.database() to the original method.
        admin.firestore = oldDatabase;
    });

    it('should return the correct data', (done) => {
        // create stubs
        const refStub = sinon.stub();

        // create a fake request object
        const req = {
            query : {
                text: 'fly you fools!'
            }
        };
        const snap = test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot({ original: req.query.text }, 'messages/1234');

        // create a fake document reference
        const fakeDocRef = snap._ref;

        // create a fake response object
        const res = {
            send: returnedDocRef => {
                // test the result 
                assert.equal(returnedDocRef, fakeDocRef);
                done();
            } 
        };

        // spoof firestore
        const adminStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'firestore').get(() => () => {
            return {
                collection: () => {
                    return {
                        add: (data) => {
                            const secondSnap = test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(data, 'messages/1234');
                            const anotherFakeDocRef = secondSnap._ref;
                            return Promise.resolve(anotherFakeDocRef);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // call the function to execute the test above
        myFunctions.addMessage(req, res);
    });
});
```

My question is how the heck do I fix this?

I previously had a test that was just passing the first snap and fakeDocRef, and my test was passing fine, but as soon as I resolve the promise with the new fake document reference, it fails...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here. I'm using `firebase-admin` version `6.4.0`. It appears that the strange snapshot function call is in the typescript itself, and not a result of the typescript compiling: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/blob/master/src/providers/firestore.ts#L73

Comment: Either of you figure this out?

Comment: Why are you sending a documentReference down the wire? What is this test achieving? Have you considered an end-to-end test might be more suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three different types of the calls, that are different:

> 1. [Operating on the Collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).
> 2. [Operating on the Documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot).
> 3. Operating on the results of the query.

They have to be used consistently. 
Please refer a documentation to see the [difference operation on the collection and the document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data).